# Need a Wordpress article grabber plugin

Tags: wordpress, aggregator, webgrabber

I'm looking for a wordpress plugin where I can add an article URL and copy the whole article (including images) when editing a new post.

I've installed lots of rss aggregators, importers, etc but none of them does this.

To be clear, I don't want to copy a whole site, I'd like to just enter an URL and get all the content and images imported to my new post.

Answer (score 0):

Save page as... and use this plugin, but be careful with copyrights. 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I'm looking for